# How to enqueue this char[] array in C?

Tags: c

I have to use a buffer of size max_cache_req_len to read in the value received from mq_receive. Here is my code that is receiving a value from shared memory and then placing it on a queue:

```
size_t received_bytes = 0;
char buffer[MAX_CACHE_REQUEST_LEN];

received_bytes = 0;
memset(&buffer, 0, MAX_CACHE_REQUEST_LEN);

received_bytes = mq_receive(mq, buffer, MAX_CACHE_REQUEST_LEN, NULL);
if (received_bytes != -1)
{
    item_type *item = malloc(sizeof(item_type));
    item->path = buffer;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);

    steque_enqueue(&queue, item);
    pthread_cond_signal(&queue_cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);
}
```

Here is my code that is taking the item off the queue, and placing it into a char* value. When I print the path, I get "".

```
void *worker(void *arg)
{
    item_type *new_item;
    char *path;
    int fd;

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);

        while (steque_isempty(&queue) == 1)
            pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cond, &queue_lock);

        new_item = steque_pop(&queue);

        path = new_item->path;

        free(new_item);
        new_item = NULL;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);

        fd = simplecache_get(path);
        sleep(cache_delay);

        printf("%d\n", fd);
        printf("%s\n", path);

        // MAKE WORKER THREAD TAKE
        if (fd == CACHE_FAILURE)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I hardcode something like:
item->path = "buffer";

Then it prints buffer from within my worker function. This is a multithreaded application, I am just unsure what to do with my char[size] array to transform it into a char* and allow it to transfer.

Nutshell:
(char*)&char[size] queued -> queue turns it into a void* -> popped off queue, turned into a char* and value is lost

Comment: You may try `strdup`? But you have to free it later on.

Comment: Oh dope I did not know that existed. Okay not a problem though, I can free it!

Comment: Just be aware `strdup()` is POSIX and not C, so if you need a portable solution, just `strlen(), malloc(), memcpy()` (which is all `strdup()` does)